# grails - update parent and children items throws out of bounds exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two classes a parent class:

```
class parentItem{
     User        user

     Date    startTime
     Date   endTime
     ------

     Date        dateCreated
     Date        lastUpdated

     static hasMany = [ childItems: ChildItem ]
```

and a child Class

```
class ChildItem{


static belongsTo = [parent : ParentItem]    
---------
Date time
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
```

In the gsp file that allows items to be edited I have a table with rows that look like this:

```
<table id="childDataTable" class="childData">
<g:each in="${ParentInstance?.childItems?.sort{it.id}}" var="childItem" status="i">
<tr class="childRow">
            <td>
         <g:hiddenField name="childItems[${i}].id" value="${childItem.id}"/</td>
         ------
        <td>
        <g:textField name="childItems[${i}].time" class="time" value="${childItem.time}"/>

            </td>               
            <td><a href="#" class="removeButton">&#10006;</a></td>  
        </tr>
    </g:each>
        </table>
```

So my question stems from the fact that in the controller I've tried to update this parentItem where some of the childItem data may also have been changed.  I need both the parentItem and the collection of childItems to update and save.

In the controller I've tried this

```
def parentInstance = ParentItem.get(params.id)
bindData(parentInstance, params)
```

and I've tried

```
def parentInstance = ParentItem.get(params.id
parentInstance.properties = params
```

Both ways I get a Out of Bounds Exception

In a case where I have two child Items the message looks like this:

```
Index: 1, Size: 1. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at com.sexingtechnologies.laboratory.ParentItemController$_closure7$$EOChoLzu.doCall(ParentItemController.groovy:158)
at grails.plugin.multitenant.core.servlet.CurrentTenantServletFilter.doFilter(CurrentTenantServletFilter.java:53)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm not sure where the error exists or how to solve it.

I've tried to extract the childItems from params map but have not been able to do so successfully.

Any help you be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could initialize the `childItems` before the data binding like so:

```
def parentInstance = ParentItem.get(params.id)
parentInstance.childItems = [].withDefault { new ChildItem() }
bindData(parentInstance, params)
```

[See here for more about the `withDefault` method](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/groovy-goodness-create-list-with.html).

Comment: That works well.  I was concerned that it would add new records and keep the originals, but was overjoyed to find that it did indeed just update the records.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yeah, it ends up accessing only the ones it's going to update. :) It would create new ones if you removed the input hidden with the id, though. Glad it worked out, you're welcome.

Comment: The problem we get with this method is that it doesn't update all of the entities passed in. It does the 1st one, and then the 2nd one twice, and skips the 3rd one entirely.